# How do I add two values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

So I have a code to subtract one value from a cell, but when I try to copy the code to make an IF function to add numbers in another cell, it doesn't work. I heard that "+" doesn't act as a plus sign, so I'm hoping to find another character that will do as needed. 
Here is the code to subtract. It works perfectly.

```
    if (editRange.getA1Notation() == "R17"){
    var updateRange = sheet.getRange("T17:Y18");
    var newValue = updateRange.getValue() - e.value;
    updateRange.setValue(newValue);}
```

And here's the plus code. It launches fine, but if I had "112" in the range *T17:Y18*, and I had "8" in *R18*, the value in the range would be "1128".

```
    if (editRange.getA1Notation() == "R18"){
    var updateRange1 = sheet.getRange("T17:Y18");
    var newValue1 = updateRange1.getValue() + e.value;
    updateRange1.setValue(newValue1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

`e.value` always returns a string and `+`  operator concatenates two strings.

#### Solution:

Use `Number`/`parseInt` to cast `e.value` to number type.

#### Snippet(s):

```
updateRange1.getValue() + Number(e.value);
//OR
updateRange1.getValue() + parseInt(e.value);
//OR
updateRange1.getValue() + (+e.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('1');//for debugging
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(e.range.getA1Notation()=="R18" && sh.getName()=='Sheet1') {//Limit action to only one cell in one sheet in the spreadsheet
    var updateRange1=sh.getRange("T17");
    var newValue1=Number(updateRange1.getValue()) + Number(e.value);
    updateRange1.setValue(newValue1);
  } 
}
```